# Unable to make options menu..shows up as context menu android

Tags: android, android-menu

I want to make options menu in android but it shows up as a context menu. here is the code.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {

     menu.add("Item1");
     menu.add("Item2");

     return true;
    }
```

Can anyone help me understand y its showing up as context menu.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public static final int ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX1 = Menu.FIRST;
public static final int ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX2 = Menu.FIRST+1;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

         menu.add(0, ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX1, 0, "item1"); 
         menu.add(0, ADD_CATEGORY_INDEX2, 0, "item2"); 

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Why do you call `super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)` twice?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a menu, do something like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = this.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

It shows up as a context menu because you don't have a layout set up for your menu, and you don't inflate it. Use the code provided, and XML code similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Menu button - Home -->
<item 
    android:id="@+id/homeButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/homeicon"
    android:title="@string/homeButton"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />
<!-- Menu button - Location -->
 <item 
    android:id="@+id/locationButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/locbutton"
    android:title="@string/locationButton"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />
 <!-- Menu button - Dining -->
  <item 
    android:id="@+id/diningButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/diningbutton"
    android:title="@string/diningButton"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />
  <!-- Menu button - Top25 -->
   <item 
    android:id="@+id/topXXVButton"
    android:icon="@drawable/topxxv"
    android:title="@string/topXXVButton"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    />
```

All this should get you going.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried this as well but still get a context menu not an options menu. I need a menu at the bottom in a grid of 2 columns and one row.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.device_menu, menu);
    setMenuBackground();
    return true;
  }

  private void setMenuBackground() {
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new LayoutInflater.Factory() {
        public View onCreateView(final String name,final Context context,final AttributeSet attributeSet) {

            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) {  
                try {
                    final LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater();
                    final View view = f.createView(name, null, attributeSet);
                    //view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_selector);

                    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                           view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.menu_selector);               
                        }
                    });
                    return view;
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    Log.e("##Menu##","Could not create a custom view for menu: "+ e.getMessage(), e);                                                                           
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(String name, Context context,
        AttributeSet attrs) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuItem1:
        //code for first menu item click     
             break;
        case R.id.menuItem2:
            //code for second menu item click      
             break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is the menu_selector.xml (in the drawable folder) :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/menu_pressed"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/menu_focused"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/menu_normal"/>
</selector>
```

And here is the device_menu.xml (in the layout folder) :

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:id="@+id/menuItem1"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_for_item_1"
        android:title="Item1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menuItem2"
       android:icon="@drawable/icon_for_item_2"
       android:title="Item2" />

   </menu>
```

And this is the colors.xml (in the "values" folder of "res" folder) :

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

             <color name="menu_normal">#ff222222</color>
             <color name="menu_focused">#ff444444</color>
             <color name="menu_pressed">#ffcccccc</color>

       </resources>
```